# Validating file name input in Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I would like to  validate input for file name and check if it contains invalid characters, in PowerShell. I had tried following approach, which works when just one of these character is entered but doesn't seem to work when a given alpha-numeric string contains these characters. I believe I didn't construct regex correctly, what would be the right way to validate whether given string contains these characters? Thanks in advance.

```
#Validate file name whether it contains invalid characters: \ / : * ? " < > |
$filename = "\?filename.txt"
if($filename -match "^[\\\/\:\*\?\<\>\|]*$")
    {Write-Host "$filename contains invalid characters"}
else
    {Write-Host "$filename is valid"}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would use [`Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars(v=vs.110).aspx) rather than hardcoding the characters in a regex pattern, and then use the [`String.IndexOfAny()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/11w09h50(v=vs.110).aspx) to test if the file name contains any of the invalid characters:

```
function Test-ValidFileName
{
    param([string]$FileName)

    $IndexOfInvalidChar = $FileName.IndexOfAny([System.IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars())

    # IndexOfAny() returns the value -1 to indicate no such character was found
    return $IndexOfInvalidChar -eq -1
}
```

and then:

```
$filename = "\?filename.txt"
if(Test-ValidFileName $filename)
{
    Write-Host "$filename is valid"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "$filename contains invalid characters"
}
```

---

If you don't want to define a new function, this could be simplified as:

```
if($filename.IndexOfAny([System.IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars()) -eq -1)
{
    Write-Host "$filename is valid"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "$filename contains invalid characters"
}
```

Comment: If desired, a regular expression pattern could be created like this: `'[{0}]' -f [regex]::Escape(([IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars() -join ''))`

Answer (score 1):

To fix the regex:

Try removing the `^` and `$` which anchor it to the ends of the string.

Comment: Removing the ^ and $ fixed it. Mathias approach using GetInvalidFileNameChars() looks good/worked as well.